# C# BitArray with leading zeros

Tags: c#, bit, bitarray

I've tried something like this:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(00001110);
```

But the result is `1110`

It seems like the BitArray cut the leading zeros.

Is it possible to create a BitArray with the leading zeros?

Comment: What ouput format are you looking for - a BitArray would not have leading zeroes.  Do you want to convert it to a string?

Comment: _"But the result is 1110"_ -- not with the code you posted, it's not. The only matching constructor would be the `BitArray(int)` overload, in which case the `00001110` would be taken literally as an `int` value specifying a `BitArray` object with one thousand, one hundred and ten bits in it, all initialized to zero. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem.

Comment: As of C# 7 you can use binary literals like, `new BitArray(0b0000_1110);`

Comment: @mikez this still just sets the size of the array (to 14). You have to pass a `byte[]` array instead. See my answer.

Comment: @adjan Oh quite right. I didn't look at the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(00001110);
```

just sets the size of the BitArray to `1110`. What you want is

```
bool[] array = new bool[] {false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false};
BitArray bits = new BitArray(array);
```

or using

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] {0x70});
```

which is rather unintuitive because the bits of the second digit are put first, and the bits of each digit are reversed in order.

Further, with C# 7.0 you can set the byte value using a binary literal as well:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] {0b0111_0000});
```